# pgRouting ways table attributes description

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

I've imported an extract of OSM data for my region of interest to Postgresql using osm2pgrouting 2.3.6 in Linux, using mapconfig_for_cars.xml configuration file, and I've found that it created tables as expected:

- ways_vertices_pgr
- ways
- pointsofinterest
- configuration

Now I wish to find a description of the data fields of the ways table, specially the cost, cost_s and priority ones, and which are used for evaluation by the routing algorithms, as I need to elaborate and put my specific cost values for my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the docs on *osm2pgrouting* are sparse at best - you will find some use cases and examples in the numerous [*pgRouting Workshops*](https://workshop.pgrouting.org/), with further hints and detailed explanations hidden inside the chapters (e.g. [here](https://workshop.pgrouting.org/2.6/en/chapters/advanced.html#exercise-9-vehicle-routing-when-time-is-money)).

As first aid, you can assume that:

- `cost` and `reverse_cost` is given as **segment length [*degrees*]**
- `cost_s` and `reverse_cost_s` is given as **traversal time (`length`/`maxspeed`) [*seconds*]**
- `priority` is [hard-coded](https://github.com/pgRouting/osm2pgrouting/blob/main/mapconfig_for_cars.xml) as *good measure*, given as `FLOAT` to allow for priority ranges (i.e. a `priority` between `1.00` [incl.] and `2.00` [excl.] refers to all major roads [`highway` to `tertiary`], with the decimal part denoting the actual road type)

---

However, *pgRouting* **does not evaluate anything by itself**; rather, it allows for (and expects) **custom SQL strings** to be passed into its functions, that in turn will get **executed as queries dynamically** - and only *their* results will get evaluated.

The tables that are created by *osm2pgrouting* are *best practice structures* only, and aim at providing a *plug&play* experience - they are in no way required for the suite of functions in *pgRouting* to work and you can freely customize their structure.